# Given $Z=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n,$ where $(E_n)_n$ decreasing sequence of sets,prove that $\partial Z\subseteq Z\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\partial E_n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $Z=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n$ where $(E_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\Bbb R^n$.
> Prove that $\partial Z\subseteq Z\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\partial E_n.$

I was motivated by the [following answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050447). I think I have another idea, but I would like to ask for a verification.

**My attempt** (directly, without a contradiction):

If $Z$ is closed, then, trivially, $\partial Z\subseteq Z\subseteq Z\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\partial E_n.$

Otherwise, there might be some $x\in\partial Z$ and $x\notin Z$. I want to show that $x\in\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\partial E_n,$ that is, $\exists n_0\in\Bbb N, x\in\partial E_{n_0},$ in other words, $\forall r>0,$ the open ball $B(x,r)=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid \|x\|_2<r\}$ contains points both in $E_{n_0}$ and outside of $E_{n_0}$.

Since $x\in\partial Z,\forall r>0,$ the open ball $B(x,r)$ contains some $x_{1,r}\in Z$ and, since $Z=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n,\space x_{1r}\in E_n,\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad(*)$

(and in particular, $x_{1,r}\in E_{n_0}$ that I'm going to find later)

Since $x\notin Z=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n,\exists n_0\in\Bbb N, x\notin E_{n_0},$ and, of course, $\forall r>0,$ the open  ball $B(x,r)$ contains a point $x\notin E_{n_0}\quad (**)$.

Now, $(*)$ and $(**)$ yield $x\in\partial E_{n_0}.$

If $x\in Z,$ then trivially $x\in Z\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\partial E_n.$

Is this legitimate? I think, if this is true, the statement holds without the requirement on $(E_n)_n$ to be a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Does these sets live in a metric space ? If not, $B(x,r)$ is not well defined...

Comment: I don't think the proposition is correct, even in a metric space, a possible counterexample would be this family of open sets $E_n=B(0,1)$ for all $n$

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: @AndreaS. : the collection you propose is non-increasing but not decreasing. Notice that in english, decreasing means $E_{n+1}\subsetneq E_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Surb Are you sure? I would rather speak of "strictly decreasing" in that case. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing).

Comment: @drhab, thank you for the edit.

Comment: @surb, for the sake of simplicity as I'm probably going to work in $\Bbb R^n,$ I included that instead of an arbitrary topological space. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: @AndreaS. sorry, I've noticed I made a typo in the tittle, now corrected by drhab.

Comment: @Spring yes, the proof seems rock solid to me.  The hypothesis of decreasing (or strictly decreasing) seems not necessary to the thesis...are there any inconsistencies that would be a consequence of this that you are aware of? Because in that case I will follow this question and be interested where your proof is wrong.

Comment: @AndreaS., to be frank, the proof seemed very straightforward so, from personal experience, I suspected I might have omitted something. I believe the other user used the assumption from the primary problem in the thread so as to prove by contradiction.